# drupal is welcoming other user after login

Tags: 6, users

I have website built on drupal 6.26.
Now i am facing a trouble that sometimes when the user logs in, the website is showing him Welcome message to another user!! for example if you login using user X, after reload of the page, it will show you a message of "Welcome Y" and shows the profile page of Y. fortunately, it shows profile Y but without Editing permission. and if you try to visit X's profile, it will be editable!!.
Any idea what could cause such ambiguity??

Comment: errant page cache()ing is the most likely suspect

Comment: are you using any special cache module?

Comment: I am not using any special caching!! i suspect that cache is behind this as well!! but could I avoid it?

Comment: can you duplicate the same issue on your local machine by opening two different browsers?

Comment: in fact it happens on more than a browser...

Comment: install **devel** module and try to debug the current logged in user `dpm($GLOBALS['user']);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys, I found the problem,,, the caching of the login block was set to 1, i just made it no-cache for this block

```
mysql> select * from blocks where module like '%ajax%';
+-----+---------------+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+--------+----------+------------+-------+--------+-------+
| bid | module        | delta | theme   | status | weight | region      | custom | throttle | visibility | pages | title  | cache |
+-----+---------------+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+--------+----------+------------+-------+--------+-------+
|  35 | ajax_register | 0     | sky     |      1 |    -40 | rightheader |      0 |        0 |          0 |       |  |     1 |
|  39 | ajax_register | 0     | garland |      0 |      0 |             |      0 |        0 |          0 |       |        |     1 |
+-----+---------------+-------+---------+--------+--------+-------------+--------+----------+------------+-------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update blocks set cache=-1 where bid=35;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> update blocks set cache=-1 where bid=39;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```